# Are we supposed to use SQL command instead of using ActiveRcord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I read an article saying that, for better performance, `find_by_sql(xxxxxxxxx)` should be used in place of `find_by_name('John')`.
Is this true?

What is the difference between these two patterns?
If you could show some examples, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: short answer - no, the example provided is a single query against a single row. A different example might be different. The traditional Rails mindset is to be less concerned about query speed and focus more on caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using Rails nor Ruby if what you're looking for is good performance.

`find_by_sql` http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class

`find_by` is a dynamic finder based on a column in your database. For example:

`Post.find_by_name('John')` will return a post object found where name = 'John'. FYI this is a LIMIT 1 statement so if you have multiple Post objects with the name John it will only return 1.

In the end, the find_by_sql is if you want to run pure SQL commands, while the find_by is a magic helper.

Comment: I already knew what you've explained to me. Thanks so much though. All I wanted to know is whether if I should use SQL command in controller if I want better performance. Shouldn't it be a trick to make it faster?

Comment: Your question is extremely contextual, and it depends on the type of data you are trying to retrieve. If there are some complicated joins, grouping, ordering, etc. then I'd agree that maybe writing a legit SQL query would be the way to go since AR has issues in those instances.